# Mounting a mobile phone: what is happening under the hood?

Tags: unity, automount

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and it automatically mounts my mobile phone (Android, Xperia Z5 Compact) when I connect it via USB. This only happens under Unity that I normally don't use.

What's the magic that is actually happening so that I can "mount" the phone with my favorite window manager spectrwm?

Answer (score 2):

[`gio`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software)) is doing the "hard work".

To mount an MTP device, you can do the following steps:

1. Connect device, select "Transfer Files" or something similar on the phone.
2. `gio mount -li | grep unix-device` and look for `/dev/bus/usb/...`. If you have several hits, remove the `grep ...` part and try again to find out which device is the phone.
3. `gio mount -d /dev/bus/usb/...` with the full path after `unix-device` from step 2.
4. The device's storage will be available at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=...` where `1000` is your user ID and may vary and the path ends with the string that can be found in `gio mount -li`'s output after `activation_root`.